# Create a buffer using CH3COOH and NaCH3COO that has a pH of exactly 3.75.?

Tags: acid-base

a 50 mL sample of your buffered solution will have to be able to withstand the addition of 25.0 mL of 0.100 M NaOH solution.

the buffered solution will break after the addition of no more than 35.0 mL of the 0.10 M NaOH.

Can someone give me an overview of how to approach this? Thanks